# Are there any "Fantasy Passports" that are recognised by other countries?

Tags: legal, passports

I've read about the [Conch Republic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4066/101) passports, and [Hutt River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Hutt_River), and am wondering - these so-called fantasy passports - are any of them actually recognised anywhere else in the world?

@mindcorrosive also pointed out the [World Passport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Passport) which the EU declared to be a 'fantasy passport'.

According [to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camouflage_passport#Legality_of_camouflage_passports): the legality is one thing - they're legal to posess in NZ and the EU, for example, but the section on effectiveness is empty... :(

Comment: There are also [Aboriginal passports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboriginal_passport) in Australia, in the news recently when Julian Assange was given one.

Comment: If you track the links to the World Service Authority claims of acceptance you will see generally letters recognizing the existence of the WSA and recognising it's documents as "identity documents". An identity document is very different from a travel document, and can't necessarily be used for travel.

Answer (score 9):

If you define "fantasy passport" as a passport of a country which isn't fully internationally recognized, then I believe the [Palestinian Authority passport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_Authority_passport) would qualify. Which in fact is recognized as travel document by some of the countries, which don't recognize Palestine as state itself.

Comment: Add Kosovo and Taiwan to that list.

Comment: If the criterium is "not *fully** recognized" then you can even add [Communist China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_with_limited_recognition#Non-UN_member_states_recognised_by_at_least_one_UN_member) to the list. International politics is messy.

Comment: Well following this criteria you could also add Israeli passports. There's a bunch of states which don't recognize the country, which leaves only "some" who recognize it. This might depend on your definition of "fully recognized", which is so far left to each reader's interpretation.

Comment: I think "passports recognized by some but not all of the other country in the world" is a different concept from "fantasy passport", no matter whether the value of "some" is "very few" or "almost all".

Comment: @hippietrail: you do realize, that if you rule out passports that are recognized by some country, the original question makes no sense at all?

Comment: I guess it would mean "are unrecognized passports sometimes recognized?" or something.

Comment: Somaliland issues passports that are recognized only by a dozen countries.

Answer (score 6):

What exactly is your definition of "fantasy passport"? Most obvious definitions already answer the question. And what exactly does "recognise" mean (the World Passport wikipedia page says that there are official documents from some third world countries that confirm its acceptance, but with dubious current validity)?

As an extreme case, consider Taiwan and China - the two governments each consider the other illegitimate and the issued passports invalid - while they are accepted in most other countries (including those that don't officially recognize Taiwan), travel between the two countries requires different documents that maintain the fiction that there is only one nation.

Comment: For definition, I go with that of Wikipedia, which I linked to.  Recognise would be accepting it as a legal document.  The World Passport seems iffy, given it's only claimed.