# Documents for travel between Republic of China and People's Republic of China?

Tags: passports, china, paperwork, taiwan

According to [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9663/13639):

> travel between [ROC and PRC by citizens therof] requires different documents [than the passports issued by each country] that maintain the fiction that there is only one nation.

What exactly are these "different documents" and how do citizens of ROC and PRC obtain them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_%26_Entry_Permit_(Republic_of_China) for PRC to ROC and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainland_Travel_Permit_for_Taiwan_Residents for the other way round

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short, mainland China (PRC) and Taiwan (ROC) don't recognize each other so they don't want to stamp each others passports / stick visa in there. The pragmatical workaround in place right now is that both nations issue another document to visitors from the other country (i.e. like a visa, but on its own piece of paper in my overly simplified words).

The details are nicely described [here for PRC citizens travelling to ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_%26_Entry_Permit_(Republic_of_China)) and [here the other way round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainland_Travel_Permit_for_Taiwan_Residents). The following is a brief and less accurate summary of mine:

- From Taiwan to mainland this is called *Mainland Travel Permit for Taiwan Residents*.

> Taiwanese can apply for the permit in China Travel Service (CTS) Limited's Hong Kong or Macau branches or through travel agencies in Taiwan.

- From mainland China to Taiwan you need an *Exit & Entry Permit for the Taiwan Area of the Republic of China*,

> a document issued by the National Immigration Agency of the Republic of China

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answer:

- For a mainland/Hong Kong/Macau resident to travel to Taiwan, they will need a "中華民國臺灣地區入出境許可證" ("Exit & Entry Permit for the Taiwan Area of the Republic of China") from the ROC authorities.

  - However, mainland residents going directly from the mainland will also need to get a "大陆居民往来台湾通行证" (not sure about the translation; maybe "Mainland Residents' Exit-Entry Permit for Travelling to and from Taiwan", or "Taiwan Travel Permit for Mainland Residents") from the PRC authorities, rather than a PRC passport, to enter and exit the PRC side.
- For a Taiwan resident to travel to the mainland, they will need a "台湾居民来往大陆通行证" ("Mainland Travel Permit for Taiwan Residents") from the PRC authorities. They will use their ROC passport to enter and exit the ROC side.